# Powershell Multiline textbox output

Tags: powershell

Using the powershell code below I am trying to output separate lines but for some reason only the last line displays. Any way to get to show multiple lines in the textbox?

```
$objTextBox3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox3.Multiline = $True;
$objTextBox3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,160) 
$objTextBox3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,100) 
$objTextBox3.Scrollbars = "Vertical" 
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox3)

$objTextBox3.Text = "TEST-" + $objTextBox2.Text + " FirstLine" + " (P) r`n  TEST-" + $objTextBox2.Text + "SecondLine" + " (P)"
```

Thought using  r`n  would work?

TIA

Comment: Did you mean to use a backtick before the r as well?

Comment: Thank you I was missing that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mike Shepard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36429/mike-shepard) has provided the crucial pointer in a comment on the question:

Your string was missing `` ` `` before the `r` in order to make `` `r`n` `` expand to a *CRLF* [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) - that is, *a Windows-style line break* composed of a [CR character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/d/index.htm) (`` "`r" ``) immediately followed by a [LF character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a/index.htm) (`` "`n" ``).

Thus:

```
$objTextBox3.Text = "TEST-" + $objTextBox2.Text + " FirstLine" + " (P) `r`n  TEST-" + 
                    $objTextBox2.Text + "SecondLine" + " (P)"
```

<sup>Note that the spaces around `` `r`n `` are retained.</sup>

Unlike PowerShell itself - which generally accepts CRLF, LF, and CR newlines *interchangeably* - the [WinForms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) `[System.Windows.Forms.TextBox]` control with `.Multiline` set to `$True` *only* recognizes CRLF sequences as newlines in terms of display.

A LF(-only) newline - which your string mistakenly, but in effect used - is quietly *ignored* when *displaying* the string in the GUI (though it is retained in the control's `.Text` property).